# The App gets recreated even when android:configChanges is specified?

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-lifecycle, android-orientation, android-configchanges

I specified in the `manifest.xml` the following tag

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="fullsensors
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardhidden|keyboard"
</activity>
```

And `android:configChanges="Orientation|keyboardhidden|keyboard"` means avoid recreation of the App in case of "orientation" OR "keyboard is hidden/visible"

And in my App class, I am calling all the activity's life cycle callbacks. And I expected when I rotate/re-orient the device that, no recreation of the App will be occured. Or in other words, the following callbacks, in order, will not be called because of `android:configChanges`. The callbacks are `onPause()` `onStop()` `onDestroy()` `onCreate()` `onStart()` `onResume()` and for every time I rotate the device, the App gets recreated and the previously mentioned life cycle's callbacks are called.

Any explanation why that happens?

Comment: not it doesn't not. If you specify `android:configChanges` onConfigurationChanged is called. Starting from HoneyComb you need also `screenSize`

Comment: @blackbelt thank you for your answer. If "android:configChnanges" does not prevent recreation of the App in case of orientation changes, so what is the use of it? Regarding screenSize, is it a callback or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have not included `screenSize` in `android:configChanges` .

According to [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)

> Caution: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the "screen size"
> also changes when the device switches between portrait and landscape
> orientation. Thus, if you want to prevent runtime restarts due to
> orientation change when developing for API level 13 or higher (as
> declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), you
> must include the "screenSize" value in addition to the "orientation"
> value. That is, you must decalare
> android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize". However, if your
> application targets API level 12 or lower, then your activity always
> handles this configuration change itself (this configuration change
> does not restart your activity, even when running on an Android 3.2 or
> higher device).

So if you want to receive `onConfigurationChanged` callback .. you have to add `screenSize` in `android:configChanges` .

Comment: thank you, it is clearer now. kindly would you please upvote my question?